# how do I add outline on focus to material button

Tags: css, angular, button, sass, angular-material

I am trying by adding

```
.mat-stroked-button, .mat-flat-button {
    &:focus, &:active:focus {
        outline-width: 3px !important;
        outline-color: red !important;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.
I would also be interested in knowing if I can remove the default focus style which darkens the button. I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Have you defined `outline-style`?

Comment: What happens when you do? In the devtools can you see if this styles are get overriden?

Comment: yes, it was getting overwritten. I think I am getting close to finding where this is getting overwritten. thank you for the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.mat-stroked-button, .mat-flat-button {
    outline-style: none;
    &:focus, &:active:focus {
        outline-style: solid;
        outline-width: 3px;
        outline-color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Do you know if I can remove the default focus style which darkens the button?

Comment: @solarapricot Yes, you would simply override the styling as you want it. If the answer is correct, then please mark it as such.